# Problems with printing a sequence

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner , I was writing a program to get a particular sequence. For example, given the input `5`, it should output the following:

```
12345
2345
345
45
5
```

This is  my program:

```
b = int(input("Enter the value"))
i = 0
c = 1
while i <= b:
    for g in range(c, b+1):
        print(g, end='')
    c = c + 1
    i = i + 1
```

This program returns the following:

```
123452345345455
```

How do I print this like the pattern above? Note that if I don't use `end=''`, then all the numbers are printed individually.

Comment: Just a side note, but note that you can drop the `c` variable, and just do `for g in range(i+1, b+1)`. Additionally, you can also just replace the `while` with `for i in range(b+1)` and avoid maintaining any variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very close!

with the `end=''` everything was conjoined, adding a print statement to the `while` loop spaced each iteration out.

```
while i <= b:
    for g in range(c, b+1):
        print(g, end='')
    c = c + 1
    i = i + 1
    print()
```

Comment: The empty string can be dropped; `print()` is fine for just outputting a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the bottom:

```
    print()
```

It will add a newline, separating out the numbers.

Comment: The empty string can be dropped; `print()` is fine for just outputting a newline.

Answer (score 0):

For b from 0 to 9:

```
b = int(input("Enter the value:"))

s=''.join([str(i) for i in range(1,b+1)])

for i in range(b):
    print(s[i:b])
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you think about this solution

```
>>> mynumber=12345
>>> a = str(mynumber)    
>>> list(str(a[i:]) for i in range(len(a)))
```

Result should be :

['12345', '2345', '345', '45', '5']

[cmd image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W02gv.png)

Comment: Well that seems like a good direction but is not the expected output... This is also not the input. The input in your example would just be `5`